# Solidity - Store random numbers to a dynamic array and return the array

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I use remix IDE. When I call the function get number I got this 0: uint256[]:
How can I change it to return the dynamic array's numbers?

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

```
contract dynamicarray { 

    uint public constant MaxNumber = 50;

    uint[] numbers;

    function randomnumber() public view returns (uint){
        uint random = uint(sha3(block.timestamp)) % MaxNumber +1;
        for(uint i = MaxNumber; i > numbers.length; i++){
            numbers.push(random);  
            return  random;
        }
    }

    function getnumbers() public view returns(uint[]){
        return  numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: The return statement is not the problem. Just tested on remix too. With a  dynamic array. My guess is that your array is empty when you return it. You can check the size before you return it to see this is the case.

Comment: push() adds a new zero-initialized element to the dynamic array and returns the new length.  To set the value of the new element you need to then directly assign it:  https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=array#members  Also, you're filling the entire array with the same (pseudo-random) number - is that the intention?

Comment: @sofend The early return means that only one iteration of the loop will happen.

Comment: @sofend i will replace the pseudo number later with Oracle or something  i just stack to the basic structure for now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract dynamicarray { 

    uint public constant MaxNumber = 50;

    uint[] numbers;

    function randomnumber() public returns (uint){
        uint random = uint(keccak256(block.timestamp)) % MaxNumber +1;
        for(uint i = MaxNumber; i > numbers.length; i++){
            numbers.push(random);  
            return  random;
        }
    }

    function getnumbers() public view returns(uint[]){
        return  numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: `randomnumber` doesn't need to be payable.

Comment: Thank you very much both

Answer (score 1):

The function is a `view`, so it can't modify state. Calling `randomnumber()` will return a value, but it won't change the `numbers` array.

Drop the `view` modifier from `randomnumber()`, and it will add one item to the array. (The early return will prevent the loop from repeating.)

Comment: Why is there a loop at all?